# React memo allowing re-rendering to forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a component defined as

```
export default function MyComp({
    ...someprops
}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const searchRef = useRef();

    return (
        <Box>
            {!showEmptyState ? (
                <LzSearch
                    onUpdate={(items) => setData(items)}
                    ref={searchRef}
                />
            ) : (
               <Box />
            )}

        </Box>
    );
}
```

Where as LzSearch is defined as

```
const LzSearch = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const {       
        ...rest
    } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const hashData = {};

    console.log(hashData);

    function updateHashData() {
       // Function is called at some point after getting data from API
       setHashData(...);
       onUpdate(...)
    }

    return (
        <Box>
            {`Some components`}
        </Box>
    );
});

export default memo(LzSearch);
```

After calling onUpdate(), my main component is updated however it then re-render my LzSearch component and resetting the hashData. I have added memo however its doing the same thing.

How can I avoid re rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the ref. `LzSearch` is rerendering because the `onUpdate` prop is changing. `MyComp` will need to use `useCallback` to keep the `onUpdate` function the same between renders:

```
export default function MyComp({
    ...someprops
}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const searchRef = useRef();

    const onUpdate = useCallback((items) => {
      setData(items);
    }, [])

    return (
        <Box>
            {!showEmptyState ? (
                <LzSearch
                    onUpdate={onUpdate}
                    ref={searchRef}
                />
            ) : (
               <Box />
            )}

        </Box>
    );
}
```

> re-render my LzSearch component and resetting the hashData

Be aware that `memo` is just meant as a performance optimization tool, not a way to fix bugs. Your component needs to work correctly if it happens to rerender for some reason. memo might stop some renders, but it can't guarantee that the component will never rerender. Examples of things that can cause a rerender even with useMemo include: changing props, changing state, changing context, strict mode's double render feature, concurrent mode aborting and then repeating a portion of the component tree.

Comment: I understand re-render can happen however I don't want to re-render just for updating something. Use callback is still not stopping it. I don't want to use ref on "data"

Comment: `Use callback is still not stopping it` are there any other props that you didn't include in your question? I notice you're using `const {  ...rest } = props;`, which you wouldn't typically do if there's just one prop.